# Javascript "Click" event on disabled input type:file in Firefox

Tags: firefox

I want to make input type="file" becomes available and clicked only when I click on some element, which is also activated it (for example, stylized span).

For this I have the Javascript parameters on span:

```
onclick="document.getElementById('upload_hidden').Disabled = false;     
document.getElementById('upload_hidden').Click();"
```

But the trouble is that in Firefox only first click removes the input attribute disabled and second - opens the file selection window. In Chrome - all OK: input become enabled and clicked by first span click.

Why, first click in Firefox does not work ? :(

http://jsfiddle.net/ey47G/

P.S. In firefox v21 - all OK. Firefox v25 and v26 - have this trouble.

Comment: Can we get a view into the source code of file "script.js"?

Comment: @reporter it is in the fiddle he distributed and I have the solution already

Comment: It was a mistake of mine. I oversaw the file list at top left corner :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could imagine that the script is already ahead when it tries to click the button - but the button is still disabled

```
var f = document.getElementById('f');
var s = document.getElementById('s');

s.onclick = function () {
  f.removeAttribute('disabled');
  setTimeout(function(){ f.click(); }, 100); // run the explorer after 100 ms
}
```

This does work.

http://plnkr.co/edit/9syOfSJHaJ4b3bhRufpv?p=preview